# How to ensure unique local state among threads for email queue processing

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

**THE SCENARIO:**

I want to ask this question regarding Parallel.For(or any other multithreading approach in C#.Net). I have to build a MultiThreaded Mailer Windows service that will send mails to all the recipients as fast as it can. I get the serialized rows from the database that contains the email message and SmtpDetails and then deSerialize them in code.

An emails may have 1000 reciepients and so on a Dual Core machine ( development machine) at least 2 threads can run simultaneously. So i use parallel.For in order ro do this. I have read about the LocalInit delegate that runs once for every thread.

**THE CODE:**

```
int itemCount = serMailObj.ReceipientList.Count;

                    Parallel.For(0, itemCount, () =>
                    {
                        return new ThreadLocalStateCache()
                        {
                            Receipient = serMailObj.ReceipientList.Dequeue(),
                            mail = serMailObj.Email,
                            SerializableSmtpDetails = serSmtpObj
                        };
                    }
     , doWork, (x) => { });

 private static ThreadLocalStateCache doWork(int instance, ParallelLoopState state, ThreadLocalStateCache threadInstance)
        {
            KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp = threadInstance.Receipient;
            SerializableSmtpDetails serSmtpObj = threadInstance.SerializableSmtpDetails;
            MailMessage email = threadInstance.mail;

                email.To.Add(new MailAddress(kvp.Key, kvp.Value));

                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
                client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(serSmtpObj.UserName, serSmtpObj.Password);
                client.Host = serSmtpObj.Host;
                client.Port = serSmtpObj.Port;
                client.EnableSsl = serSmtpObj.EnableSSL;

                    try 
                    {           
                        client.Send(email);
                        Console.WriteLine("sending mail....");
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {

                        throw;
                    }


            return null;
        }

public class ThreadLocalStateCache
    {
        public KeyValuePair<string, string> Receipient { get; set; }

        public MailMessage mail { get; set; }

        public SerializableSmtpDetails SerializableSmtpDetails { get; set; }
    }
```

The above code is pretty straight forward. The localInit delegate constructs a local object foreach thread. and then the doWork tries to process the queue.

**THE PROBLEMS:**

1. I am getting multiple mails for each recipient. seems as if the email object is being shared among threads.
2. getting failure sending mail sometimes.

Kindly explain as to how i can isolate the mail and smtpclient objects in each thread. and process the queue.

**EDIT 1:** If the multithreading gurus would help me  please tell that is there any way for every thread to have a unique copy of its local variables and not shared ones. Since the MailMessage object is not immutable i cannot create a clone of it also. apart from deseralizing it in each thread(which would ensure a new object is created)  is there any magic way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be problems due to `doWork()` returning `null`. As I learned when answering [your recent comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604082/whats-wrong-in-this-parallel-for-code), the thread local object should be passed between subsequent invocations of the Parallel.For body at the same thread, because it is supposed to work as an accumulator; see [the usage example at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460703.aspx). It's unclear what happens when you return `null`, but I would fix that and see whether it makes difference.

Answer (score 1):

below might be the issue:

```
serMailObj.ReceipientList.Dequeue()
```

Try using ConcurrentQueue (.NET 4) or put locks around so that one thread at a time can Dequeue it.

also make to sure Concurrent classes or locks anywhere yo uhave access to shared resource from threads.

> A Queue <(Of <(T >)>) can support
>   multiple readers concurrently, as long
>   as the collection is not modified.
>   Even so, enumerating through a
>   collection is intrinsically not a
>   thread-safe procedure. To guarantee
>   thread safety during enumeration, you
>   can lock the collection during the
>   entire enumeration. To allow the
>   collection to be accessed by multiple
>   threads for reading and writing, you
>   must implement your own
>   synchronization.

Comment: Assuming my understanding is correct..since the dequeue is taking place in LocalInit delegate it should run only once for each thread. I am more worried about the email object that is being shared.

Comment: yes, but if multiple threads try to dequeue at the same time, it might become inconsistent state. best to use ConcurrentQueue i would think

Comment: have you considered using ThreadPool for this ? not sure if you get huge benefit of using Parellel tasks for this.

Comment: yes..i have tried using ThreadPool for this. but since i am a newbie in multithreading i cant understand the code that i got for that. Got the code from SO itself. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101891/how-can-i-send-mailmessages-using-multiple-threads. The Interlock and decrement bits of the code. parallel.for seems much easy to me since it takes care of the synchronization for me.